# Can't select items in ListBox when CanDrag=True

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm having trouble enabling drag (as in drag&drop) in an UWP ListBox. The selection stops working when I do that.

I have an UWP ListBox that contains an ItemTemplate with a single TextBlock in it. Everything was fine with the selection of items until I enabled CanDrag (i.e. drag&drop) on the TextBlock in the ListItem. After this I can't select items in the ListBox any longer by clicking on the items in the list. I can change selection by moving the focus with the arrow keys but selection with mouse interaction is no longer possible. If I set CanDrag back to False, selection starts working again.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
            <ListBox x:Name="addProcessorListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessorTypes}"
                     SelectionMode="Single" DoubleTapped="OnDoubleTapped">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Margin="8,2,10,2" Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ProcessorType">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="18,8,10,8" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontSize="15" CanDrag="True" DragStarting="Processor_DragStarting"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I tried changing the ListBox to a ListView, but the same behavior persists, i.e. selection does not work when clicking on the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue. I've reported it to the relevant team. They're investigating this issue.

As a workaround, you could use ListView control, but you do not need to drag the TextBlock in its ItemTemplate. You could choose to drag the whole ListViewItem by setting `CanDragItems="True"` and handling the `DragItemsStarting` event.

```
<ListView x:Name="addProcessorListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessorTypes}"
                 SelectionMode="Single" DoubleTapped="AddProcessorListBox_DoubleTapped" CanDragItems="True" DragItemsStarting="AddProcessorListBox_DragItemsStarting">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Margin="8,2,10,2" Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="18,8,10,8" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontSize="15" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have confirmed that the best approach is ListView as we have it implemented in our github sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop)

Actually the problem isn't quite related to ListBox/ListView but with

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
```

The following [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) mentions that Stretch will stretches the child element to fill the allocated space of the parent element. But in this case, what is the size of parent space? Selection won't fail if specified Left/Right/Center but only with Stretch.

So actually this is a coding issue and you will need the property to set the size of parament element.